# How to add Zip MIME Type in Mozilla?

Tags: firefox, mime-types, winzip

I have a question, and I'm finding too difficult to solve.

If you press Tool/Options in Mozilla web-browser, then **Applications** there you will have a list of MIME Types that you can manage some actions like SAVE, or ALWAYS ASK option... on each file type.

But, unfortunately, in another PC, I have not the WinZip MIME type associated with Mozilla.

I'm on W7 and using in both Mozilla 30.0.

Does someone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Follow [the instructions here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file#w_adding-download-actions) and see if they work. Tell me if it does/doesn't

Comment: Tried and it works! Thanks, the problem I had before, is that I had at first disabled "Do this automatically for files like this from now on"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a 'download action'. Firefox adds the setting for specific file types as you come across them - in your other computer, you might not have downloaded a WinZip file before. [This](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file#w_adding-download-actions) is how you do it:

1. On the web, find a link to a WinZip file.
2. Click on the file link to download it.
3. Select how you want Firefox to handle the file:

   - Open with: Saves the file to a temporary folder and opens it in the default application for that file type. To select an application, click Choose....
   - Save file: Saves the file to the download folder (specified in the Firefox General panel).
4. In the Opening file window, check mark Do this automatically for files like this from now on.

[image]

Make sure you enable the `Do this automatically for files like this from now on` option.